# How to Invoke AWS Sagemaker API with c# .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sagemaker

I have trained and deployed a model in AWS Sagemaker, Now I am trying to invoke the endpoint with client as c# .NET.
In the below code, it seems, I am getting errors because of invalid value of Body parameter.

```
AmazonSageMakerRuntimeClient aawsClient = new AmazonSageMakerRuntimeClient();
Amazon.SageMakerRuntime.Model.InvokeEndpointRequest request = new Amazon.SageMakerRuntime.Model.InvokeEndpointRequest();
request.EndpointName = "sagemaker-mxnet-py2-cpu-2018-01-23-07-04-11";
request.Accept = "text/csv";            
request.ContentType = "text/csv";
//request.Body = compressedMemStream;
Amazon.SageMakerRuntime.Model.InvokeEndpointResponse resposnse = aawsClient.InvokeEndpoint(request);
```

I have tried by passing a MemoryStream which written with a '.gz' file or with '.jpeg' file. By executing InvokeEndPoint(), Getting error as: "**unable to evaluate payload provided**"

Answer (score 0):

You mention here that you're sending a `.jpeg` file as the body of the request, but from your code sample it looks like you're setting the `Accept` and `ContentType` as `text/csv`. Try invoking your endpoint with the request `Accept` and `ContentType` set to `image/jpeg`.